# How to install Ghost CMS with Node.php?

Tags: php, node.js, npm, ghost-blog, ghost

I've tried to install Ghost CMS (https://ghost.org/) with Node.php (https://github.com/niutech/node.php) on shared hosting, but I failed.
I modified the node.php file to install the recommended version of Node.js (v0.10.40). The installation went flawlessly. Then I've tried to run the `npm install --production` command with Node.php, but it failed. Here's the output:

```
Failed to execute '/path_to/node/bin/node /path_to/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (8)
Failed. Error: 1
```

What should I do? I think i'm in the wrong directory, but I don't know how to change the directory with Node.php.

Comment: Is `npm` correctly installed on the machine?

Comment: I don't know exactly. I've used Node.php to install Node.js. There weren't any errors during the installation, so I think it's installed correctly.

Comment: I assume you have terminal access to the server?

Comment: No, I don't have terminal access. That's why I'm trying to install it with Node.php.

Comment: Even with php, you can execute terminal commands with `shell_exec()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this as the host is missing the C compiler for one of the node modules.

I would just use the pro version. It is well worth not having to backup or update to the latest version on each release which isn't easy yet. You can use Digital Ocean as well to host it but you will need to learn a little about server management.